# What is the best way to create an Observable which directly emits after creation?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am asking myself what would be the most proper and semantically correct way to create an observable which emits directly after creation?

Of course I can always do something like this `of(unkown)`, `of(undefined)`, `of(null)`, `of(true)` and so on, but what would be the "correct" way to do this, is there any reference?

Comment: the not clear question, cause `of(SOMETHING)` is still `cold` and would run only after subscription

Comment: yeah.... this question is option-based... but whats wrong with asking how to write semantically correct code?

Comment: 1rts - it wasn't me who downvoted, 2nd - there is a difference between `of(true)` and `Promise.resolve(true)` because for `of(true)` you need to subscribe such as it is cold(lazy evaluation) and promises runs regardless when you want them to - this not semantic difference, this difference in what is lazy vs eager evaluation.

Comment: that is why from the question it is not clear what you want to do + yes, this question doesn't have "research efforts" at least about "creational observables"

Answer (score 1):

`.of()` is correct way, that's why it is there.

Comment: I haven't thought of ignoring the param but, basically this would be the same as `of(undefined)` or not?

Comment: .... tested it `of(true)` is emitting directly `of()` isn't

Comment: I have upvoted the answer before testing because it seems logical.... but it is wrong,... I have tested it you can put any value in `of` as param as long as there is a value even undefined the observable will emit but if you just do `of()` the observable is not emitting

Comment: @Nickolaus that's expected behavior: `of` with value emits that value; `of` without - does not. What's wrong there? Logically `of()` **does not** equal to the `of(undefined)`. This statement generalizes to any `f()` and `f(undefined)`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create a `BahviorSubject` which is inherited from `Subject` and `Subject` is inherited from `Observable`

In the constructor it takes a value that emit it when it created

```
x : BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(10);
```